# Does it help to play a fake sound when confronted with a wild animal?

Tags: safety, animals

I was thinking about heading to a place where there is a chance to confront a coyote. It worried me a lot then..this question popped up.

If I have big enough speaker that can play sound of coyote's predator, does it help?

Comment: *Humans* are coyotes number one predator. Just make yourself heard and you'll be fine. There are thousands of coyotes around here, I've even been bit by a coyote before (they're cute when they're little, but don't try to pet one...). They are extremely timid animals, you aren't going to need to do much else other than be smelt by one in order to spook it.

Comment: If you are lucky, you will hear coyotes at night.  Just enjoy the serenade.  As for confronting a coyote, you will have to run very fast after it.

Comment: Coyotes are probably not the best example, since they're completely harmless to humans. Perhaps there's an example with an animal that presents a legitimate threat to your safety. See https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/how-dangerous-is-a-band-of-coyotes-to-a-lone-unarmed-human

Comment: In fact, on three occasions I've been lucky enough to see coyotes before they knew I was there, but only because I was completely camouflaged and intentionally descented for hunting. In one case the coyote never saw me. In the other two, merely turning my head for a better view was enough to put the fear of God into them, and they practically turned inside out to run away.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes!

Not a silly question at all and surprisingly easy to answer: *yes*!

There are even sound-systems exactly for that use.

> Try sound. Sound can have an excellent impact on a coyote that has
>   wandered into your yard or campsite.
>
> - Try banging trash can lids or anything else that is noisy to scare    the coyote off.
> - Yell and make a lot of noise in any way possible.
> - Motion activated alarms can be useful. An even more tech-savvy option    is the new Anti-Coyote sound system. This system relies on
>     the fact    that cougars occasionally kill coyotes. The systems emit
>     replicated    cougar sounds, and may keep coyotes away.
> - Propane exploders can be used to deter coyotes on farms and ranches.

From [Wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Keep-Coyotes-Away-from-Campsites-or-Homesteads)

> The USDA’s Denver Wildlife Research Center developed a frightening
>   device called the Electronic Guard
>   (EG). The EG consists of a strobe light and siren controlled by a
>   variable interval timer that is activated at night with a
>   photoelectric cell. In tests conducted in fenced pastures, predation
>   was reduced by about 89%. The device is used in Kansas and other
>   states to protect cows/calves from coyote predation. Most research on
>   the effectiveness of this device, however, has been done on sheep
>   operations. Suggestions for using the unit differ for pastured sheep
>   and range operations.

From [icwdm](http://icwdm.org/handbook/carnivor/coyotes.asp)

So, it's more important that you even make sound in the first place than what sound it is. But as you've the choice with your speaker setup, you should either use Wolf, Mountain Lion, Bear or Cougar sounds as they are the most dangerous predators (in this order) for coyotes.

### Further reading

- Don't forget to checkout [this pdf](http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1280&context=icwdm_usdanwrc):

  > Coyote-Activated Frightening Devices For Reducing Sheep Predation On Open Range

Summarized list of additional steps to take according to Wikihow:

- Use fencing
- Try sound
- Use negative reinforcement or the element of surprise if you happen across a coyote in your yard or campsite
- Eliminate food sources liked by coyotes
- Keep pets away from coyotes
- Remove junk piles from your property
- Try wolf urine
- If these humane solutions don't help, consider calling in a professional

### Coyote Shaker

A good method to get rid of coyotes is to use a coyote shaker — a soda can filled with pennies or pebbles and sealed with duct tape. This device scares the approaching coyote in three ways. Through:

- Aggressive hand motion
- Loud noise
- Reflective light

Shake or throw this “coyote shaker”.

Comment: *The systems emit replicated cougar sounds, and may keep coyotes away* … … 10 minutes later, a cougar approaches…

Comment: @gerrit You just have to play a wolf or bear sound then :D Make sure you've an iPod with a strong playlist though.

Comment: @OddDeer Thus follows force escalation. What sound will you play once you have a polar bear in your yard? ;)

Comment: @fgysin Easy: just play "The Hoff - Looking for freedom".

Comment: Nobody preys on the Hoff.